# where Server in Domain save his Site?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server

I Had problem in Exchange that the mailbox Database was dismounted, Status was service down, I checked in Event viewer what was the problem, and I saw he doesn't find the Site.

I remembered: I change the Subnet in
Active directory Sites and Services for the new Subnet ip I wanted/Needed and I change at each computer's adepter to the new ip into that subnet.

And then I saw Exchange problem,
I Tried Logout because I wanted to Reload again the user Token, That didn't helped.
I Tried Restart for the computer/server of exchange, that fix the problem.

Why is that, Where did Active directory set at computer where is the site or what is the Subnet of the computer?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: where is Server Fault?

@MarcusMüller